# How to only trigger event when an item is selected (ListView)?

Tags: c#, listview

I've been using this property of a `ListView`:

```
SelectedIndexChanged
```

However, it gets triggered also when item is unselected.

What is the best event if I only want event to be triggered when an item is actually selected, and to be called only once? Not twice in a row like `ItemActivate`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `SelectedItems.Count` property in your `ListView`, return whenever its `0`, or handle the event if its greater than `0`, so all you need is an if statement in your event handler such as

```
if(yourListView.SelectedItems.Count == 0)
    return;

//Do your thing
```

Or:

```
if(yourListView.SelectedItems.Count > 0){
   //Do your thing
}
```